# Dynamic Join Advice

Tags: .net, asp.net, sql

I'm looking for some advice, please bear with me whilst I try and explain this!

I have a situation at the moment where I generate a news feed based on actions on content types, the table in a really basic form might resemble:

```
<userid, int, FK> | <actionType, int, FK> | <contentType, int, FK> | <objectID, int>
```

So for example... userid 2000, performed action type 1, on contentType 1, on object id 2001

The objectID is the unique id of the object, relative to the content type.. subsequently can't be enforced by a constraint because depending on the contentype, the table will be different.

Now, taking the example I gave before, (2000, 1, 1, 2001), in order to display this in the site I would then need to query the object, lets say contenttype '1' is 'users' and action is 'slapped', in order to generate this:

Karl slapped George

I would join on the userid field to get karl, but the need another query to get the user 2001 details..

Does this make sense?

So i'm ending up with a situation where, to do a "select top 10" news feed, i'm needed a minimum of 11 queries (one for the initial, then 10 lookups).

I want a better way to do this, and the only way I can think of would be to do it all in the stored procedure, with a big case statement, a cursor, and some temporary tables :x

Any advise is welcome!

Thanks in advance, 
Karl

Comment: What did you slap George for? Oops, sorry. I meant to ask, how many different content types are there? Is that a fixed number?

Answer (score 0):

I see two possibilities, there are probably other solutions:

1/ create a view that combines all `<contenttype>, <objectid>` combinations, something along the lines of

```
CREATE VIEW ObjectIds AS (
       SELECT <ID_OF_CONTENTTYPE_1> as ContentType, ID from <TABLE_1>, <possibly other needed columns>
 UNION SELECT <ID_OF_CONTENTTYPE_2> as ContentType, ID from <TABLE_2>, <possibly other needed columns>
 -- etc
)
```

You can then join with this view instead of the original table

2/ refactor the fact table to use real FK's instead. That does mean that you have to know all 'content types' up front though.